# UICollectionView's cell disappearing

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**What's happening**

Currently I have an application that uses two `UICollectionViews` inside a `UITableView`. This way I create a Pulse News look like application. My problem with this is that sometimes the 6th and 11th row disappears completely, leaving a blank space where it should be the cell. I wouldn't actually mind, if all the cells were like this (and this way I could assume that I wasn't doing things correctly), but the thing is, is just happening with those specific ones.

**My theory**

The 6th and 11th rows are the ones that appears when I start scrolling, so by default I am able to see 5 cells, and when I do the first horizontal scrolling the 6th comes up (blank space sometimes).

**What I have**

The only thing I am doing at the moment is this:

```
 [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:CELL_NIB_NAME bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
```

On the `viewDidLoad`. And on the creation of the cell:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self.DataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [cell buildViewWithDictionary:dictionary withReferenceParent:self.referenceViewController];

    return cell;
}
```

So on my understating nothing fancy going on here. I though there was something wrong on the data source (a dummy JSON file), but sometimes it works ok and the cell shows, so I guess from that part is ok.

So my "question": Does anyone knows what's going on? I don't really like to say that it's a bug from iOS, but I can't think of anything else.

---

**Edit 1.0**

The amazing part is that this method

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Is going from `indexPath` [0,4] to [0,6] without calculating the [0,5]. First time I actually see this happening in iOS.

---

**Edit 2.0**

I have switched the way I am creating the cells, and instead of dequeuing I am using the old way:

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CELL_NIB_NAME owner:self options:nil];
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

Still the same sad result.

Comment: I get the same problem, but the cells that disappear end up being rendered below the previous cell! Very odd. I've assumed it was a bug in iOS.

Comment: Stranges things are happening. =/ But still an outstanding controller..

Comment: I have classic grid view created using collection view. I have 3 cells in a row with small gaps. Same thing happens here but seems like very randomly. From time to time one cell is placed at 4th place in a row and in it's expected place is nothing.

Comment: Weirdly when I return "1" on the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegates minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex and minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex, the bug fixed. I am guessing it must be the layout problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So, what did work?

1) Subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

2) Set the flowLayout of my `UICollectionView` to my new subclass.

3) On the init method of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass, set the orientation you want:

```
self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```

In my case it is Horizontal.

4) The **important part**:

```
-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
   return YES;
}
```

At this moment, I should theorise a bit, but honestly I don't have a clue.

Comment: Take a look at this bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/12433891 Could it be what you're encountering?

Comment: I have to be honest Rob, strange things happen when using `UICollectionView`, not sure if it's related or not.

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with cell width and height? I'm having the same rendering problem with a horizontally scrolling collection view. I get disappearing cells when my cell width is 70 and height is 70. If I keep the cell width at 70 and change the cell height to 69, it renders correctly. I can reproduce this situation every time.

Comment: @BryanLuby after doing what I did in the `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:`it's working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @rob-mayoff! I was having the same problem. Always random items in the first column disappearing after scrolling down and then up again. Using the one of the subclasses in http://openradar.appspot.com/12433891 fixed it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, but the solution here did -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927027/uicollectionview-flowlayout-not-wrapping-cells-correctly-ios
If you output the rects in that function, you'll see it creates two rows / columns so you have to filter it down to 1.

Comment: This solved my crash in `layoutSubViews` that only occurs in iOS 9 (iOS 10 & 11 are fine), thanks.

Answer (score 20):

The above answers didn't work for me, but after downloading the images, I replaced the code
`[self.myCollectionView reloadData]` 
with 
`[self.myCollectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];` 
to refresh the collectionview and it shows all cells, you can try it.

Comment: Stupidly, this worked for me as well...what's going on with `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Tried other solutions above, none were working (Swift 3), this one fixed the bug. Strange...

Comment: Can't believe that actually worked, and it added animations for me too.

Comment: Sometimes some random cell disappears too :/

Comment: For me, this made the cells re-appear, but they disappear again when the user scrolls past then back to that point

Answer (score 8):

None of the solutions given by anyone helped me in my custom layout that we need to have in our app.
Instead, I had to do this: (And yeah, **IT WORKS**!!!)

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGSize size = [self collectionViewContentSize];
    rect.size.height = size.height*2;
    NSArray *atrributes_Super = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    return atrributes_Super;
}
```

After all, UICollectionView is just looking for the attributes for the elements to be displayed in your screen's rect.

Comment: Similar thing happened here.
My implementation of layoutAttributesForElementsInRect was not returning the attributes for the desired cell, that in turn was being set as .hidden = YES.

Answer (score 3):

Rob's tip about the bug helped me. The bug states that if the section insets and cells widths and spacing add up exactly to the width of the screen then the first column sometimes randomly dissappears and reappears for some cells in some places. Rather than subclass or change the cell widths, I changed the section insets for left and right in my storyboard from 6 to 4 and it I haven't seen the problem again.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it using Rob's solution. But I am really glad it worked for you man.

Answer (score 2):

As I run the same problem suddenly and spent some time figuring out one of possible reasons of cell disappearing during the scroll, I will add my answer as well.

#### Prerequisites of the problem:

1. You have a `UICollectionView` instance
2. You have a `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutSubclass`

#### The problem

Cells disappear from the Collection View after scrolling to the certain point.

#### The source of the problem is in wrong subclassing of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

As it explicitly said in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout):

> Every layout object should implement the following methods:

```
- collectionViewContentSize
- layoutAttributesForElements(in:)
- layoutAttributesForItem(at:)
- layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind:at:) // (if your layout supports -supplementary views)
-layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind:at:) // (if your layout supports decoration views)
- shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange:)
```

By relying on `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` implementation of methods above we miss the fact, that `func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)` and `collectionViewContentSize` will generate wrong **contentSize** (the size that would be correct if all the cells would have `itemSize` size and the content size would be corresponding. As soon as scroll `offsetY` will be greater that `contentSize` height cell will all disappear.

#### The solution

The solution is in proper `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclassing. Override all the methods that are [required to override](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout) and everything will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into an issue where all UICollectionView cells were disappearing on scroll.

This happened because I had declared

```
extension UICollectionViewLayout {
    static let defaultLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        return layout
    }()
}
```

... meaning the same layout instance was being used in multiple UICollectionViews. I had meant to make that a computed var. Hope this helps someone who's accidentally using the same layout object in multiple collection views.

Comment: `layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case (vertical scroll, with cells disappearing in first view), cells were disappearing due to incorrect estimated size. It seems, `UICollectionView` uses the estimated size to calculate the items to load in first view. I'd set the estimated size too high which was resulting in wrong calculations for number of items to load in first screen.

The moment I made the estimated height bit low, all the cells appeared correctly.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into disappearing cells recently and found that rather than skipping 'hidden' cells we were accidentally inserting 0x0 sized cells.  The resulting behavior was very confusing and did not suggest these invisible cells were the issue.  We would see the correctly sized cells and layout, but a few of the valid cells would consistently disappear after scrolling off/on screen.  I have no idea why intermingling 0 sized cells would cause this behavior, but removing them fixed the problem.  This may not be causing your problem, but this may be helpful to devs searching for similar symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

What caused the cells to disappear in my case was that the data source was being deallocated prematurely. `UICollectionView.dataSource` is a weak property, which means that unless you keep a strong reference to it, the object will be deallocated at the end of the scope in which you created. The problem manifested itself with disappearing cells as soon as I tapped on the `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

I hade to add `myCollectionView.reloadData` inside `cellForRowAt` of the cell so make sure every time creating a cell it get updated with the new data and to avoid disappearing of the cells and avoid overlapping of the content of the cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DiarioTableViewCell
cell.tag = indexPath.section
cell.collectionView.reloadData() // this what fixes my cellsDisAppearing
cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() //just to be sure, maybe it's not necessary

return cell
```

}

Answer (score -1):

For me this issue seemed to be related with the way i make my collectionview adapt to an open keyboard to prevent content overlaps.

in my observer to respond to KeyboardWillShow i had this:

```
var userInfo = obj.UserInfo[UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey];
if (userInfo is NSValue value)
{
    var rect = value.CGRectValue;
    var windowOffset = this.Superview.ConvertPointToView(this.Frame.Location, UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow);
    var newHeight = rect.Y - windowOffset.Y;

    this._controller.CollectionView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, this._controller.CollectionView.Frame.Width, newHeight);
}
```

After changing it to this:

```
var userInfo = obj.UserInfo[UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey];
if (userInfo is NSValue value)
{
    var rect = value.CGRectValue;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, rect.Height, 0);
    this._controller.CollectionView.ContentInset = contentInsets;
    this._controller.CollectionView.ScrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

The cell disappearance issue completely went away. This is C# from working with xamarin but i hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not a UICollectionView‘s bug, maybe your not return right data in `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect` method.

You can see this demo: https://github.com/lqcjdx/YLTagsChooser , all cells can appear when scolling the UICollectionView.