# Cell disappearing after scrolling 2 - 3 times in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm facing a strange issue while scrolling my `UICollectionView`. It's showing a blank view without any cells in it.

It strangely hides my cell or removes my cell, I don't know, but I'm unable to find any solution.

I have tried these solutions from SO:

**1st :** Tried to create custom class of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and do as directed with all different methods but unable to solve my issue.

**2nd :** Tried below method to reattribute and recalculate my cell size :

```
-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
   return YES;
}
```

Links I followed :

Que1: [UICollectionView's cell disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360975/uicollectionviews-cell-disappearing)

Que2: [UICollectionView items disappear when scrolling with my own UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779292/uicollectionview-items-disappear-when-scrolling-with-my-own-uicollectionviewflow)

Please guide me whats wrong with simple collectionview with custom cell.

**Reference Image :**

Before Scroll:
[image]

After Scroll:
[image]

Comment: Please start by taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), then learn to create an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consult your [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I am answering my own question.

As I am stuck for the last 2 days on this issue.

As I am using `CollectionViewController` and add that `Controller` view into my current using controller so it's disappearing my collection view cell.

> **Reason:**  due to `ARC` releasing that `delegate` & `datasource` connection and that collection view can't able to get cell while I am
> scrolling from top to bottom.

**Solution:**

I solve this problem in 2 ways.

**1st :** Create that `CollectionViewController` in my current `VC` not in Service & `JSON` Parser class due to `delegate & datasource` connection loss.

The most important part in the below code is `addChildViewController` by this it will not releasing delegate connection and works as expected.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
CardListViewController *objCardListViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CardListViewController"];
objCardListViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.cardMainView.frame.size.width, self.cardMainView.frame.size.height);
[self.cardMainView addSubview:objCardListViewController.view];
[self addChildViewController:objCardListViewController];
```

> but as per my requirement I needed this collection view at many places
> so I need to generalize this collection view.

So I choose the 2nd way which is `ContainerView` with *add child controller* and I connect this `CollectionViewController` with container view so I can use it as many places where I need this list.

Strange but true.

Hope this will help someone if facing the same issue.

Thanks & Happy Coding.

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thanks. This should be more visible :)

Comment: `addChild(controller)` saved my day, thank you!