# UICollectionView decoration view above some cells when deletesections method called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom layout inherited from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` used to achieve for each section to add backgroundview. The first time to show that there is no problem, but when I use `deletesections` method to delete the first section, some cells on the display in the decoration view below, the strange thing is to delete the data and then call the `reloadData` method will normal display.

I have put the code into GitHub:https://github.com/TonightGod/UICollectionView-DecorationView

pictures:
[after deleteSections method called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gunrp.jpg)

code:

```
@interface MyCustomLayout()
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *decorationViews;
@end


@implementation MyCustomLayout


-(NSMutableArray*)decorationViews
{
    if(!_decorationViews)
    {
        _decorationViews=[NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _decorationViews;
}


- (void)prepareLayout {
    [super prepareLayout];

    [self.decorationViews removeAllObjects];
    NSInteger sections=[self.collectionView numberOfSections];
    for(NSInteger section=0;section<sections;section++)
    {
        NSInteger items=[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
        if(items>0)
        {
            CGRect firstItemFrame=[self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]].frame;
            CGRect lastItemFrame=[self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:items-1 inSection:section]].frame;
            UIEdgeInsets sectionInset=self.sectionInset;
            if([self.collectionView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:)])
            {
                sectionInset = [(id<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>)self.collectionView.delegate collectionView:self.collectionView layout:self insetForSectionAtIndex:section];
            }

            CGRect sectionFrame=CGRectUnion(firstItemFrame, lastItemFrame);
            sectionFrame.origin.x=0;
            sectionFrame.origin.y-=sectionInset.top;
            if(self.scrollDirection==UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal)
            {
                sectionFrame.size.width += sectionInset.left + sectionInset.right;
                sectionFrame.size.height = self.collectionView.frame.size.height;
            }else
            {
                sectionFrame.size.width = self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
                sectionFrame.size.height += sectionInset.top + sectionInset.bottom;
            }

            NSString *identifer=[self.delegate collectionView:self.collectionView decorationViewIdentiferAtSection:section];

            if(identifer)
            {
                UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *decorationAttributes=[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:identifer withIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:section]];
                decorationAttributes.frame=sectionFrame;
                decorationAttributes.zIndex=-1;
                [self.decorationViews addObject:decorationAttributes];
            }
        }else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }

}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:attributes];

    [allAttributes addObjectsFromArray:[self.decorationViews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nullable evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *obj=evaluatedObject;
        return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, obj.frame);
    }]]];

    return allAttributes;
}



@protocol MyCustomLayoutDelegate <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

-(NSString*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView decorationViewIdentiferAtSection:(NSInteger)section;

@end

@interface MyCustomLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@property(nonatomic,weak) id<MyCustomLayoutDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: Please check this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592580/cell-disappearing-after-scrolling-2-3-times-in-uicollectionview

Comment: Thank you, but did not solve my problem, my question appears after calling deletesections

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through CustomLayout of collection view ??

Comment: add an decoration view at each section, means give each section a background view