# UICollectionView design flow layout for attached image

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I attached images what I have done and what I have to achieve. Please guide me to achieve this.

*I have done till now:*

[image: I did]

*I want to achieve the following:*

[image: Want to achieve]

*Here is my code:*

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size; 
    if (indexPath.row == DIGIT_INT_2 || indexPath.row == DIGIT_INT_6 || indexPath.row == DIGIT_INT_7)
        size = CGSizeMake(150, 68); 
    else if (indexPath.row == DIGIT_INT_3 || indexPath.row == 13)
        size = CGSizeMake(150, 150);
    else
        size = CGSizeMake(68, 68);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code because it's super hard to help otherwise.

Comment: @WaiHaLee thanks for reply sir till now i added the uicollectionview and added defined the size of items using flow layout delegate method:-- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{CGSize size;    if (indexPath.row == DIGIT_INT_2 ||indexPath.row == DIGIT_INT_6 || indexPath.row == DIGIT_INT_7) {size = CGSizeMake(150, 68); }else if (indexPath.row == DIGIT_INT_3 ||indexPath.row == 13) {size = CGSizeMake(150, 150);}elsesize = CGSizeMake(68, 68);return size;}

Comment: I meant to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30258206/edit) your question to include the code. That way, you can have formatted code so that it's easier to read.

Comment: Have you looked at [RFQuiltLayout](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout)?

Comment: Thanks Azat for your reply i solved it by my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the answer and i achieved it by customise the UICollectionViewFlowLayout class and inheriting the method `- (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect` and play with the previous item frame and current item frame.

But after this a new problem came one item disappear after scrolling. I failed to find why this happening. After two days work i have to move another way to achieve this. 
Thanks  Wai Ha Lee for formatting the question.

Now my disappear problem solved by this question:- [UICollectionView's cell disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360975/uicollectionviews-cell-disappearing)