# Swift - UICollectionView content disappear while scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift5

After updating from swift 4 to swift 5, my UICollectionView is disappearing while scrolling (ONLY horizontal view) because in the gif file there's another UICollectionView but it's vertical, I didn't face this problem in swift 4, I searched stack overflow and I saw a lot of answer but it didn't helped me ,

[this is a gif. file show the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHK39.gif)

this is my heightForRowAt function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
        
    case 1:
        return 200
    case 2:
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
        
    case 3:
        if (self.topAlbumsArray.isEmpty){
            return 300.0
        }else{
            
            return 120.0
        }
        
        
    default:
        return 280
    }
}
```

this is the collectionView function

```
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

          return CGSize(width: 150, height: 200)

      }
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
          return 8
      }
  
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
          return 8
      }
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
          return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360975/uicollectionviews-cell-disappearing

Comment: all of them nothing change @DeepaBhat

Comment: Looks like giving a proper height to collectionview should work. Since the row height for tableview cell is dynamic and even collection view doesnt have a height, is causing the problem. Please add a height constraint greater than or equal to, for collection view.

Comment: where. should I give the height? @DeepaBhat