# uicollectionview Loads wierdly

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a collection view with custom collection cell.set with flowlayout as

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(250, 480)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
[self.templateCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

I set it horizontal but still a cell is misplaced in figure see `att mmp` misplaced & it will back in its correct position if we scroll and load it back. Can anyone suggest whats wrong in this ?

[image: collection]

Comment: need some more description...provide some more info..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a work around on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927027/uicollectionview-flowlayout-not-wrapping-cells-correctly-ios/13389461#13389461) that works for me.  Below is the fix I used edited for horizontal scrolling.  Basically just filtering out the attributes item that is providing the bad frame down below.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
     NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
     NSMutableArray *newAttributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:attributes.count];
     for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in attributes) {
          if (attribute.frame.origin.y + attribute.frame.size.height <=    self.collectionViewContentSize.height) {
               [newAttributes addObject:attribute];
          }
     }
     return newAttributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It generally happens when we haven't given proper cell spacing. Make sure, while populating cells of uicollectionview, cell spacing should be given.
Also go through [UICollectionView flowLayout not wrapping cells correctly (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927027/uicollectionview-flowlayout-not-wrapping-cells-correctly-ios?lq=1) may it help you out.