# UICollectionView Fast Scroll wrong behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with fixed cells size, without any flowLayout classes.

When I scroll quickly, the cell falls down under the previous like this Sometimes!!!

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481365/collectionview-loads-wierdly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once encountered this problem and [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481365/collectionview-loads-wierdly) once.Not answered yet by anybody.The workaround what i did is making the `CollectionView` height adjust such that the cell will be visible properly.Made the height of `UICollectionView` with +2 pixel than the height of the cell.

Comment: I've got this same problem, but the cell increases in size as it approaches the center of the screen so I can't solve it by shrinking down the collectionView around it.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927027/uicollectionview-flowlayout-not-wrapping-cells-correctly-ios/13389461#13389461) that you don't have to resize your collectionView.