# Reduce space between cells in a collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

There's a huge space between the `cells` in the `collectionView` as shown in the image below. How can i reduce it.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(100, 50);
    return mElementSize;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}
```

[image]

UPDATE

[image: enter code here]

Update

[image]

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the identity inspector to adjust the spaces straight from the Xib, does adjusting the "Min Spacing" or "Section Inserts" help?

[image]

Comment: Please look at my Identity inspector. I have added it to the post above. There;s still no effect.

Comment: Have you got any constraints that might be affecting the spacings?

Comment: I have added the constraints to my post above. Can you tell if i am missing anything ?

Comment: Using a storyboard I fixed it myself by setting Min Spacing for Cells and Lines to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the size of the `UICollectionViewCell` depending on your screen size to reduce the gap between two `UICollectionViewCells`.

**Update 1**

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      return CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/4, 300);
      // A total of 4 views displayed at a time,  we divide width / 4, 
      // and cell will automatically adjust its size.
}
```

HTH Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: I am using `objective-c `

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class for collectionView flowlayout and set flowlayout in IB with custom class

```
@interface NDCollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end
```

//  Created by Nick Snyder on 11/13/12.
//  https://gist.github.com/nicksnyder/4075682
//  [UICollectionView flowLayout not wrapping cells correctly (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927027/uicollectionview-flowlayout-not-wrapping-cells-correctly-ios)
//  NDCollectionViewFlowLayout.m

```
#import "NDCollectionViewFlowLayout.h"

@implementation NDCollectionViewFlowLayout

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
  NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
  NSMutableArray *newAttributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:attributes.count];
  for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in attributes) {
    if ((attribute.frame.origin.x + attribute.frame.size.width <= self.collectionViewContentSize.width) &&
        (attribute.frame.origin.y + attribute.frame.size.height <= self.collectionViewContentSize.height)) {
      [newAttributes addObject:attribute];
    }
  }
  return newAttributes;
}

@end
```

[image]
[image]