# UICollectionView Custom Cell to fill width In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've been trying to figure-out how can i make the cell fill the width, as you can see in the picture the width between the cells is too big. i am using custom cell with only one imageView.

[image]

I tried to customize it from the storyboard but i guess there is no option for that or it should be done programmatically. 
[image]

my UICollectionViewController :

```
 @IBOutlet var collectionView2: UICollectionView!

    let recipeImages = ["angry_birds_cake", "creme_brelee", "egg_benedict", "full_breakfast", "green_tea", "ham_and_cheese_panini", "ham_and_egg_sandwich", "hamburger", "instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg", "japanese_noodle_with_pork", "mushroom_risotto", "noodle_with_bbq_pork", "starbucks_coffee", "thai_shrimp_cake", "vegetable_curry", "white_chocolate_donut"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
         return recipeImages.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        cell.recipeImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipeImages[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: just check this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649687/reduce-space-between-cells-in-a-collectionview/29649994#29649994

Comment: What is the contentResizingMode of your image view? ...and are you using auto layout?

Comment: Well its in different sizes for example : 560 × 350 , no I'm not using any kind of auto layout.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You need to do this programatically.

Implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in your view controller and provide the size in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let kWhateverHeightYouWant = 100
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, CGFloat(kWhateverHeightYouWant))
}
```

You will also want to call `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` inside your view controller's `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` so that when the main view's dimensions change (on rotation, for example), the collection view is re-laid out.

## Swift 4 Update

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                            layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                            sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let kWhateverHeightYouWant = 100
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat(kWhateverHeightYouWant))
}
```

Comment: i did exactly as you said, but when i run the app, it hangs on the launch screen and the Xcode shows this message "Message from debugger: Terminated due to Memory Error" !!

Comment: It seems that the memory error is coming from somewhere else. Do you have a stack trace that I can look at? Or take a picture of the Debug Navigator or breakpoint if there are no logs.

Comment: its a window without any stack trace , it says .. The app "CollectionView" on "** iPhone" quit unexpectedly. Message from debugger: Terminated due to Memory Error . and Ok button

Comment: Google the error message. I'm guessing you have a retain cycle somewhere.

Comment: ok, i figured to let it compile but the result as shown : http://i921.photobucket.com/albums/ad53/Johann_1990/IMG_0222.png , should be two images in the same row stick to each other not only one.

Comment: @Aoli You just need to provide `collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2` in `CGSizeMake()`, then. Also, change your image view's `contentMode` property to either `ScaleAspectFit` or `ScaleAspectFill`.

Comment: If you just want to affect the width how do you know (in that function) what the height was to have been?

Comment: Your tip on invalidating the layout was what I've been looking for, for hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Use Following code for set the width of `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {        
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3);
}
```

Comment: From where i can get the screen size as variable ?

Comment: let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width

Comment: it doesn't work as i expect, because it actually increase the width between cells.

Answer (score 11):

Inside your view controller override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let itemWidth = view.bounds.width / 3.0
        let itemHeight = layout.itemSize.height
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

(`collectionView` property is your collectionView)

Comment: its giving me "Terminated due to Memory Error" on runtime ?

Comment: Possibly because it's causing an infinite loop. When the view is done laying out the subviews (what `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is for), you invalidate the layout and lay it out again.

Answer (score 8):

Also in Swift 3,

Make sure your view controller complies with the following:

UICollectionViewDelegate,
UICollectionViewDataSource,
**UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

If you are using swift 3, use this method:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    }
```

**Notice the changes:**

1. add `_` before `collectionView` in the method name
2. `NSIndexPath` changes to `IndexPath`

Answer (score 3):

I have the same requirement, in my case below solution is worked. I set **UIImageView** top, left, bottom and right constraints to **0** inside         **UICollectionviewCell**

```
@IBOutlet weak var imagesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // flowlayout
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/3 - 5, height: screenWidth/3 - 5)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    imagesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I wanted to show two columns and 3 rows in the UICollectionView

I added UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate to my class

then I override sizeForItemAt indexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellHeight = (collectionView.bounds.size.height - 30) / 3 // 3 count of rows to show
    let cellWidth = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - 20) / 2 // 2 count of colomn to show
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat(cellWidth), height: CGFloat(cellHeight))
}
```

The 30 is the Line spacing, the 20 is the insent between cells

Answer (score -1):

Programatically set the `itemSize` to `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/3`

Comment: Did you mean the imageView or the cell (for item size)? Thanks

Comment: The cell, I'm assuming your image will be autoresized to fill the width/height

Answer (score -1):

In my case, assuming every cell has a width of 155 and a height of 220. If I want to show 2 cells per row in a portrait mode and 3 for landscape.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var itemsCount : CGFloat = 2.0
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait {
        itemsCount = 3.0
    }
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/itemsCount - 20, height: 220/155 * (self.view.frame.width/itemsCount - 20));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to change the `itemSize` of your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. That is where you can get the most accurate size of the `UICollectionView`. You don't need to call invalidate on your layout, that will be done for you already.

Answer (score -1):

For my case, autolayout was only allowing the cell to grow to its content size even though I overrode the cell size in the storyboard, conformed to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, and implemented `sizeForItemAt`. So I made a dummy UIView the width of the cell's bounds.

UICollectionViewController:

```
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.bounds.width - 40
        return CGSize(width: width, height: collectionView.bounds.height / 3)
    }
}
```

Cell (I'm calling this method on dependency injection):

```
private func updateViews() {
    let padding:CGFloat = 8
    let innerView = UIView()
    innerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    innerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    innerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    innerView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    contentView.addSubview(innerView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        innerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bounds.width - padding*2),
        innerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
        innerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
        innerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: padding),
        innerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding)
    ])
}
```