# Cells disappearing with horizontal scrolling in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uikit

I have been stuck on this weird problem for a little while and cannot seem to figure it out.

**Setup**

- **A** is a `UICollectionView`
- **B**s are A's `UICollectionViewCell`s
- **C** is a `UICollectionView` added as a subview of B when the user taps in B

  ```
  +------------------------------+
  |A                             |
  |                              |
  | +----------+    +----------+ |
  | |B         |    |B         | |
  | |----------|    |          | |
  | |          |    |          | |
  | |C         |    |          | |
  | +----------+    +----------+ |
  +------------------------------+
  ```

**Issue**

When initializing C's `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` scroll direction property to `.horizontal`, ***and scrolling past the second cell***, C's cells are vanishing.

As a bonus *C itself is vanishing from the UI*: the user is again able to tap into the cell, which performs all the actions done on C's usual removal. When tapping again to normally re-show it, actions triggered on C's displaying are fired but C is still visually nowhere to be found.

**The issue does not happen when scroll direction is set to `.vertical`.**

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or any clue as to what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT** Actual implementation

(B)

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    //...

    private let cellId = "cellId"

    private lazy var label: UILabel = {

        return CollectionViewCell._label()
    }()

    fileprivate lazy var gallery: UICollectionView = {

        return CollectionViewCell._gallery()
    }()

    //...

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        isOpaque = true
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        layer.cornerRadius = 8

        // ...
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func onSwitchDisplayGallery(_ isDiplaying: Bool) {

        switch isDiplaying {

        case true:

            addSubview(label)
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.height / 5.25).isActive = true

            gallery.register(NestedCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
            gallery.delegate = self
            addSubview(gallery)
            gallery.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            gallery.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            gallery.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
            gallery.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, constant: -frame.height / 5.25).isActive = true

        case false:

            print("removed cv")
            // ...
        }
    }

    //...
}

extension CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return gallery.frame.size
    }
}


private extension CollectionViewCell {

    class func _gallery() -> UICollectionView {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cv
    }

    class func _label() -> UILabel {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 15)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }
}
```

(C)

```
import UIKit

class NestedCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    private let containerView = NestedCollectionViewCell._containerView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        isOpaque = true
        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = .white

        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true

        //...
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

private extension NestedCollectionViewCell {

    class func _containerView() -> UIImageView {

        let view = UIImageView()

        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**
I have tried Nick's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927027/uicollectionview-flowlayout-not-wrapping-cells-correctly-ios).

When the scroll direction is set to `.vertical`, everything is normal.

When it is set to `.horizontal` C displays no cell...

Comment: could you show your code? Are you using anchors? or did you use storyboard?

Comment: @kbunarjo: Everything is done programmatically with anchors yes. See edited answer with implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly, silly rookie mistake. Leaving this here if anyone else needs glasses like I do :)

The collection view did not have an horizontal constraint...

```
addSubview(gallery)
gallery.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
gallery.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Correcting this to

```
addSubview(gallery)
gallery.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
gallery.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

fixed it (obviously).