# UICollectionViewFlowLayout estimatedItemSize does not work properly with iOS12 though it works fine with iOS 11.*

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, ios12, uicollectionviewflowlayout

For UICollectionView's dynamic height cells we use,

```
if let layout = self.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
}
```

with the proper constraint of height and width, it works fine with iOS 11.* versions but it breaks and does not make the cells dynamic for iOS 12.0

Comment: Maybe related: [In iOS 12, when does the UICollectionView layout cells, use autolayout in nib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51375566/1033581). In particular, my answer with AutoLayoutCollectionView may help.

Comment: I figured out: In iOS 12 estimatedItemSize is compiled and added as a size constraint. It conflicts with other specified constraints. ale84's solution works for me, but there're also conflict constraints showed up on the console. My personal experience with collection view is that every OS version there're some bugs here and there, very annoying.

Answer (score 68):

In my case, I solved this by explicitly adding the following constraints to the cell's contentView.

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    // ...

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Addresses a separate issue and prevent auto layout warnings due to the temporary width constraint in the xib.
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Code below is needed to make the self-sizing cell work when building for iOS 12 from Xcode 10.0:
        let leftConstraint = contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor)
        let rightConstraint = contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor)
        let topConstraint = contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
        let bottomConstraint = contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
    }
}
```

These constraints are already in place inside the xib of the cell, but somehow they aren't enough for iOS 12.

The other threads that suggested calling `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` in various places didn't help in my situation.

Sample code here: https://github.com/larrylegend/CollectionViewAutoSizingTest

This applies the workaround to code from a tutorial by https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2:

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue, this worked for me for now. 
And as well I'm invoking this code only for iOS12:
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) { }

Comment: It's working. Thank you, You have saved my days men.

Comment: How did you ever figure this out? I don't think Apple mentioned this huge breaking change anywhere. It's sad that they make us pollute our app code with boilerplate garbage like this.

Comment: @AndrewKoster an intuition and a lucky guess. I think this code is just a workaround and Apple should fix this.

Comment: Amazing. just what i needed

Comment: Thanks @ale84, +100 for this answer. You really saved my day

Comment: Yes, it worked like charm. This answer should be the accepted answer for this question.
And I second @ale84 as this bug should be addressed by Apple.

Comment: Hi @ale84, The code works great when I use it to load the cell with dynamic height. However, when I reload the same collection view using `invalidateLayout` or `reloadData` method, the height of the visible cell become usual maximum height. Once I scroll view,  things goes to normal. Have you encountered any such issue? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Sample source code can be found below: https://github.com/mysticvalley/CollectionViewAutoResizeiOS12Issue

Comment: @RajanMaharjan Hi, from looking at your sample, I think you should set the `itemSize` of the layout to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`, and the `estimatedItemSize` to an estimated value.

Comment: @ale84, I already got it working after updating the `itemSize` to `.automaticSize`. Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: Wow I wondered why every UICollectionView tutorial on the internet doesn't work. Amazingly, this helped.

Comment: Amazing but it works. The same story bud shorter is: contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

Answer (score 10):

Based on `ale84`'s answer and because of the fact I needed that iOS 12 fix in multiple places I created a UICollectionViewCell extension which I named UICollectionViewCell+iOS12:

```
extension UICollectionViewCell {
    /// This is a workaround method for self sizing collection view cells which stopped working for iOS 12
    func setupSelfSizingForiOS12(contentView: UIView) {
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let leftConstraint = contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor)
        let rightConstraint = contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor)
        let topConstraint = contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
        let bottomConstraint = contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
    }
}
```

And then in your collection view cells we do something like this (if your cell is created in IB):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    if #available(iOS 12, *) { setupSelfSizingForiOS12(contentView: contentView) }
}
```

Comment: `UICollectionViewCell` has the property `contentView`. No need to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C version of above answer:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
        // Addresses a separate issue and prevent auto layout warnings due to the temporary width constraint in the xib.
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        // Code below is needed to make the self-sizing cell work when building for iOS 12 from Xcode 10.0:

        NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [self.contentView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leftAnchor constant:0];
        NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [self.contentView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor constant:0];
        NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [self.contentView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor constant:0];
        NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [self.contentView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor constant:0];

        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint]];
    }

}
```

For Objective-C lovers like me ;) cheers !!!

Answer (score -1):

i have the same problem. using UILabels to size the collectionview. if i run `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` before reloading the data it does an ok job of sizing the labels.

still not quite right. it's tough for me to figure because i'm running it on the simulator vs. device.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this problem by putting such code into my subclass of UICollectionViewCell

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes {
    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [self systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)];

    CGRect alteredRect = layoutAttributes.frame;
    alteredRect.size = size;
    layoutAttributes.frame = alteredRect;
    return layoutAttributes;
}
```

and subclassing UICollectionView like this

```
@interface CustomCollectionView ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldInvalidateLayout;
@end

@implementation CustomCollectionView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (self.shouldInvalidateLayout) {
        [self.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
        self.shouldInvalidateLayout = NO;
    }
}

- (void)reloadData {
    self.shouldInvalidateLayout = YES;
    [super reloadData];
}

@end
```