# In iOS 12, when UICollectionView is created using Self Sizing cells with constraints, upon reload layout has wrong height until I scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a weird issue in iOS 12 when using solution as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718787/uicollectionviewflowlayout-estimateditemsize-does-not-work-properly-with-ios12-t/52389062#52389062).

It works great when collection view loads for first time, however when I try to reload the collection view using either `collectionView.reloadData()` or `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`, a weird height to cell is added.

Once I start scrolling everything will be normal again. Please see images below. First image shows working heights for cells after view loads. Second one shows cells after reload is pressed.

[image: Works great at first load]

[image: After clicking on reload bar button]

The reload bar button calls following method.

```
@objc func reloadCollectionView() {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Please view sample project in GitHub [here](https://github.com/mysticvalley/CollectionViewAutoResizeiOS12Issue) for reproducing the issue. I used Xcode 10.1 and 10.2 to reproduce the issue.

Any kind of help or direction for resolving the issue would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the real problem is that self sizing collection view cells do not work and never have. See my discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51375566/in-ios-12-when-does-the-uicollectionview-layout-cells-use-autolayout-in-nib/52428617?r=SearchResults#52428617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is coming from you calling:

```
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

in your project.

If you reset this to something like:

```
layoutFlow.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 100)
```

Then it immediately runs smoother.

**Note:** It is worth noting that the estimated height you set your cells to matters. If you set it to 0 then `reloadData()` will scroll the collectionView to the top. Setting an accurate value seems to work best in testing

There are still a few bugs which seem to be fixed by removing the

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

and swapping it for something like

```
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
```

I don't know the specific use that you are wanting this for so I can't fully test how it should be but invalidateLayout seems like the wrong way to reload the collectionView.

Comment: replacing UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize resolve my problem. Do you have an idea why this is happening? Everything looks fine until I dynamically change the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 12, contentView get constraint by itemsSize default(50x50).
Manually set edge constraints to get
right resize

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```