# UICollectionViewFlowLayout estimatedItemSize breaks constraints during rotation but itemSize is totally fine

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'd like to display a bunch of UICollection view cells with images and labels and adjust their widths according to width of the labels.
I don't want to override `sizeThatFits()` neither to override `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting`

As far as I understand all I need to do is to just make sure that AutoLayout in my cell is OK and then use property `estimatedItemSize` to make cells self sizing.

Unfortunately it's ***kinda*** true in my case. UI looks fine but when I rotate the device I've got plenty of broken constraints. However when I just use the property `itemSize` and make all my cells with fixed size (like 100x150) then everything is fine during rotations, no AutoLayout issues.

This is how I constrained my UICollectionViewCell. I don't really know why I had to use dummy `UIView` as a "main" view for `UIStackView` but Xcode cried a lot with AutoLayout issues without it. For testing purposes I put this view outside cell but in separate `UIViewController` to test if AutoLayout is OK - seems like it is.

[image]

And this code for my `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let items: [Item] = [
    Item(title: "Cell 1"),
    Item(title: "Cell 2"),
    Item(title: "Cell 3"),
    Item(title: "Cell 4"),
    Item(title: "Cell 5"),
    Item(title: "Cell 6")
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        fatalError("Impossibruuu - layout is not FlowLayout")
    }

    myCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell")
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 50
    // line below makes AutoLayout angry during rotations
    layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize 
    // this is completely fine
    //layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 150) 
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

    cell.text = items[indexPath.row].title
    return cell
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when using `layout.estimatedItemSize` I've got completely bizarre log:

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-06-22 18:53:18.841709+0200 CollectionViewSelfSizing[55280:2953587] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
  Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6e170 UIImageView:0x7fe820c1ac90.height == 100   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6ebc0 V:[UIStackView:0x7fe820c1a020]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe820c19e40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6ec60 V:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7fe820c1a020]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe820c19e40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6ed00 V:[UIView:0x7fe820c19e40]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe820c19c60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6eda0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fe820c19e40]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe820c19c60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6cd70 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fe820c1a020.top == UIImageView:0x7fe820c1ac90.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6cf50 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UILabel:0x7fe820c1d0c0'Cell 1']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fe820c1a020 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6ce60 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIImageView:0x7fe820c1ac90]-(19)-[UILabel:0x7fe820c1d0c0'Cell 1']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d644b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fe820c19c60.height == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6e170 UIImageView:0x7fe820c1ac90.height == 100   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You've only got two views, the image view and the label, so what's the stack view for?

Comment: Well, to reduce amount of constraints, I think. Maybe it is a overkill, I'll try without stack view (so `UIImageView` constraint to top with 0, height == width == 100 and centred horizontal. `UILabel` constrained with 19 points below image, leading and trailing with 0 and no bottom constraint. Let me check that.

Comment: Stack views do not reduce the amount constraints. They increase them!

Comment: Well, I tried what I told. Not only I've got warnings during rotations but my layout looks very bad (at least it was perfectly fine previously).

Comment: I'm ready to think that `estimatedItemSize` + auto-layout simply does not work anymore :) I dunno, I've created crazy simple pet-project to test this (needed for my work) but I think I will stick with `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`

Comment: Well, I think it has _never_ worked. I (and many others) have provided workarounds here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51375566/in-ios-12-when-does-the-uicollectionview-layout-cells-use-autolayout-in-nib (In fact I was tempted to mark your question a duplicate of that one.) However, those answers generally still expect you to know how to use autolayout.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if link provided is a duplicate because I've got layout right but issues during rotation. I studied all solutions, even tried  `layoutAttributes.size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)` in method `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_:)` but no luck. Also I removed all my XIB file for custom cell, created everything in code (subviews, constraints, no stack view). Result? Still got issues during rotation. I submitted bug to Apple with ful Xcode project included. The only way to fix it is to use `itemSize` or delegate method. End of story.